# Can't add libDeezer.a: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DeezerConnect"

Tags: ios, deezer

I'm trying to use Deezer SDK for iOS. I have tried to add the libDeezer.a from `Target > Build Pases > Link Binary With Libraries` but it did not work and it said :
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DeezerConnect"``

Then I tried whith pods `pod 'Deezer'`but now the problem is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestSerializer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WoMTotalManager.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WoMTotalManager in WoMTotalManager.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WoMTotalManager.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_WoMTotalManager in WoMTotalManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Is there any conflict between Deezer and AFNetworking ?

### Edit

Solve it with `Target > Build Settings > Build Active Architecture Only` set to NO in both my project and Pods project

### Edit 2

Git commit, close and re-open Xcode. The error is back

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$_WoMTotalManager in WoMTotalManager.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestSerializer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in WoMTotalManager.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in WoMTotalManager.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$_WoMTotalManager in WoMTotalManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Comment: Arch x86_64 means you're building for the simulator. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, and on my device in the future

Answer (score 0):

The first error can come from the Deezer iOS SDK as it does not support x86_64 (nor armv7s or arm64). But the two other errors come most likely from your pod and project configuration.

You mention that you set the `Target > Build Settings > Build Active Architecture Only` setting on the debug configuration. That may be the problem. Try to set it to YES.

Hope that helps.